# Can't Refer to Window Width/Height in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, window

I'm a novice to html/css/js and am trying to learn canvas. I want to make a canvas that is the size of the window, no matter the size of the window, then I want to draw an additional rectangle within that window on which to start drawing a maze game. I got the canvas resize with window to work, but only by setting the body's overflow:hidden (when I didn't have that set, the height was always too large). I'm wondering if this is what is now causing a problem. When I try to create a smaller rectangle inside the main canvas rectangle, I set the rectangle width to half the window size but it goes far off the screen. What am I doing wrong? I just want the rectangle to be clearly within the perimeter of the main canvas so I can see all edges.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var ctx;
var ww;
var wh;

drawcanvas();

$(window).resize(function() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ww, wh);  //won't this clear only the bottom     rectangle?
drawcanvas();
});



function drawcanvas() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ww = window.innerWidth;
wh = window.innerHeight;

ctx.canvaswidth = ww;
ctx.canvas.height = wh;
ctx.fillStyle ="blue";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ww, wh);

ctx.strokeStyle = 'orange';
ctx.strokeRect(10, 20, ww/2, wh/2);

}



});
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="maze2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="maze2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Maze</title>
</head>




<body>


<canvas id="canvas">Your browser does not support Canvas.</canvas>



</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin:0px;
overflow:hidden;
}

#canvas {
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe your `<body>` has some padding? Do you have this code somewhere for us to test?

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up your css correctly to have the canvas take the entire physical screen (inner screen) then the below will work.

Basically dont use window width and height, size the canvas properly with css and use the canvas clientWidth and height

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   var cW;
   var cH;
   size();
   drawcanvas();

   $(window).resize(function() {
       size();
       drawcanvas();
   });

   function size(){
      cW = canvas.clientWidth; // if you did your css correctly this will work
      cH = canvas.clientHeight;
      canvas.width = cW, // if the size has changed the canvas will be blanked out automatically
      canvas.height = cH;
   }

   function drawcanvas() {
     ctx.fillStyle ="blue";
     ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cW, cH);

     ctx.strokeStyle = 'orange';
     ctx.strokeRect(10, 20, cW/2, cH/2);

   }
});
```

P.S. format your code better next time